# Detecting dynamic query-string to create nested routes with React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, query-string

I wan't to create a catalog that use array formated query-string in order to select one or more filters (ranges, colors, categories...). The catalog is a page of the website, reachable from "/catalog".

I already use the TransitionGroup module on my main router, but I wonder if it is possible to set another route inside a route which should only check if there's one or more query-string after the catalog path, so re-render only a part of the catalog with CSSTransition (and not the whole page) when query-strings change.

Current route :

```
            <Router>
                <Route render={({ history, location }) => (
                    <TransitionGroup>
                        <CSSTransition key={ location.key } timeout={500} classNames="default">
                            <Switch location={location}>
                                <Route path="/catalog" render={() => <Catalog
                                    location={ location }
                                    history={ history }
                                />} />
                            </Switch>
                        </CSSTransition>
                    </TransitionGroup>
                )} />
            </Router>
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: So you want to create nested router? If I understand correctly, this article should help you: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/

Comment: No I cannot use this way ! This need to be a specific path like "/:ID" after a link, in my case I only have query-string like "/catalog?color[]=brown&color[]=blue".